# Android image list view using json

Tags: android

I want to create an image list view using JSON .
JSON link-https://yts.re/api/v2/list_upcoming.json.
and I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: explain more to help you out, and also tell what you have tried so far

Comment: its like please write me code. you could show some efforts so we help you more.

Comment: its very easy.atleast try before asking straight away

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) for JSON parsing in Android.

For creating the image list view, google will return everything you need like:

- [custom listview with image and text](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)
- [other custom listview with image and text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
- [Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Hope it will help you.